# Popup.html is not working in Chrome extension. How can I get it working again?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popup

When I click on the extension icon in Chrome, nothing pops up. What it should do is pop up the popup.html page.

I even tried my old working version of the extension that I made over a year ago. However it does not work either, which leads me to believe that Chrome must have changed something with regards to how it handles the popup.html for a Chrome extension.

Additionally, if I right-click the icon and choose "inspect popup", the option is disabled (greyed out).

Here is my code:

**MANIFEST**

```
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/icon.png",
    "popup": "html/popup.html"
  },
```

**THE POPUP FILE: `/html/popup.html`**

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
   <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
   </head>
   <body>
    TEXT TEXT TEXT
   </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The field is `default_popup` not `popup`. Try changing it, then it should work.

Comment: lol I just figured it out at the same time. Google much have changed it.

Comment: Yeah, they changed it with [manifest V2](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifestVersion.html#manifest-v1-changes)